# reporting and parameters in C#

Tags: c#, parameters

I have a stored procedure receives two parameters and shows a set of data I try to pass to a report two parameter.

But I did not show the result aye or wrong?!

```
 private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("ID", "652840400399");
     ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("N_OM", "1");
     Form2 c = new Form2();
      c.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1, p2      });
      c.reportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
      c.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
      c.Show();
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You are passing the parameters to the report, not the SP, do you pass those parameters to the SP from the report?

Comment: No ...I want it programmatically ... And left it by default

Comment: If you want it programmatically, where is your data source ?